# Why didn't the toppings on my pizza stick to the dough?

Tags: pizza

I made homemade pizza the other night and it was delicious except for the fact the toppings wouldn't stay on the cooked dough. It was a Chicken Alfredo pizza with green peppers, onions, mushrooms, and chicken. I used a metal round pizza pan to bake the pizza and the taste was amazing! However, like I stated earlier, the topping and the cheese would fall off. Why is this? How do I make it stick to the dough? Maybe I put too many toppings on the pizza, but I believe I put a perfect, good amount. Thanks for the feedback! (:

Comment: Was there any cheese?  Your ingredients above don't mention any.  Cheese is generally what makes things "stick" on a pizza.

Comment: I see "topping and cheese" referenced.  What about sauce? Did you have any between the cheese and shell?  Also, what type of cheese did you use - if mozzarella, was it fresh, whole milk or part skim?

Comment: FuzzyChef: I used cheese on my pizza. I mentioned it in the paragraph but I'm sure it was easy to miss! But yes, I did use cheese (:

Michael: I used regular alfredo sauce for the sauce and I used mozzarella cheese. The cheese was fresh from the deli and I grated it myself at home.

Comment: I was thinking maybe it is the dough because it was pretty thick but it was golden and crispy so I wasn't sure what happened to the toppings.

Comment: The oil/fat content of the sauce can play a part in this, a napoli sauce dries out, but a cream-based sauce can demulsify and provide the grease to stop things from sticking together.

Comment: Hmmm, that definitely makes sense. I'll attempt to make pizza again next week and use your advice. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Probably, you spreaded too much sauce on your pizza base; that is why melted cheese could not get onto the base.

You might make that pizza in a hasty. So, you put your uncooked pizza in an overheated oven.

You need to select the mozzarella cheese which can work as like as glue stick used in heat-gun. I believe you can make your pizza perfectly after 2/3 more trial and error.